# Username of a user is displayed in a weird format

Tags: discussion

Why is the following user's name not displaying properly in recent questions (you can go to questions and check)?

[User Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5989986/f%CC%B6%CC%9F%CC%BC%CD%95%CC%BC%CD%8E%CC%9F%CD%94%CC%A3%CD%89%CC%B3%CC%8C%CC%94%CC%82%CC%82%CC%89%CC%8E%CD%A6%CC%8E%CC%81%CD%90%CC%8E%CD%A0)

**User's name in recent questions list:**

[image]

---

**User's name in User profile page:**

[image]

**Is it allowed on Stack Overflow?**

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please can you tell me whether i can use it (if yes where i can), because if i use it comments or post then it will be like spamming the post.

Comment: You can use it any text (simply because SO provides full Unicode support, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/3001761), see e.g. this famous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761. But just because you can doesn't mean you should!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for  response. Everyday there is something new i learn in SO enjoying it.

Comment: By the way, somebody changed this user's username since these screenshots were taken.

Comment: @MrLister - So did the user change it back then? Their profile still shows Zalgo text http://stackoverflow.com/users/5989986/user5989986

Comment: @MartinSmith That's the about me text. Not as harmful as the name itself!

Comment: We need a zalgo tag. Preferably one using unicode!

Comment: I'd like to see [glitchr_](https://twitter.com/glitchr_)'s account..

Answer (score 9):

Yes that's ugly and actually disturbs readability of comments.

Yet it's allowed, since nicknames will take any kind of Unicode and render it correctly.

Comment: Having said that it doesn't mean we have to actually accept users doing that.

Comment: @Flexo Looks like that, yes.

Comment: "ugly" is a very subjective term and "beauty is in the eye of the beholder".

Comment: @KoryGill - when 99% of the users actively dislike this, it stops being a matter of ugliness and starts being a matter of discourteous behavior on the part of the perps.

Comment: @DeerHunter please link us to the poll that shows a result of 99% against zalgo text.

Comment: @DodgerThud If someone were to make a poll "Should we disallow zalgo text in usernames?" I'd vote to disallow it. Same for comments if it could obscure other people's comments.

Comment: If we should allow it - vote here

Comment: Disallow - vote here

Comment: Should we disallow Greek characters in user names?